# Read Excel values and create variables from column names in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Say I have an Excel file:

[image]

I need to create `n` variables called `$col1` up to `$coln` and read in their respective values.

What is the best approch? I have been trying with a hashtable but I need to be able loop through the columns. This is my code. I have not wraped it around a loop yet. I can create the column names manually but I need to be able to index the columns in the Excel file.

```
$ExcelRowToRead = 2;

$ListOfColumns = @{"Job_name" = 1 ; "Run_time_start" = 2}   
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application;
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open("pathtofile.xlsx");
$workbook.sheets.item(1).activate()
$WorkbookTotal=$workbook.Worksheets.item(1)
$ListOfColumns["Job_name"]  = $WorkbookTotal.Cells.Item($ExcelRowToRead, 1) # This needs to be an index
$ListOfColumns["Job_name"].Text
```

Comment: the simplest solution that does NOT require any 3rd party code is to use the COM object to export the sheet as a CSV and do the other work in PoSh using the `Import-CSV` cmdlet. ///// if you can use a 3rd party module, take a look at the ImportExcel module. it's quite nifty ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking Lee_Dailey's advice here and saving first to a CSV:

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open("pathtofile.xlsx")
$sheet = $workbook.Sheets |
    Where-Object Name -eq "SheetName" |
    Select-Object -First 1
$tempCsv = New-TemporaryFile
$sheet.SaveAs($tempCsv, 6)
$sheetData = Get-Content $tempCsv | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

At this point you have an object where you can extract its properties via `$sheetData.col1`, `$sheetData.col2`, etc. but if you really need them as separate variables, perhaps:

```
$sheetData |
    Get-Member |
    Where-Object MemberType -Eq NoteProperty |
    ForEach-Object {
        New-Variable -Name $_.Name -Value $sheetData.$($_.Name)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, why do you use 6 in the `SaveAs` method?

Comment: This is the XlFileFormat enum (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat) from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas.

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't have / want Excel:

via [GitHub - dfinke/ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel#readme)

```
> # Install-Package ImportExcel 

> $sheetData = Import-Excel '.\Excel 001.xlsx'

> $sheetData[0]

col1   col2   col3
----   ----   ----
value1 value2 value3


> $sheetData[0] | 
    Get-Member | 
    Where-Object { $_.MemberType -eq 'NoteProperty' } | 
    Select-Object -Property Name

Name
----
col1
col2
col3


> $sheetData |
    Get-Member |
    Where-Object MemberType -Eq NoteProperty |
    ForEach-Object {
      New-Variable -Name $_.Name -Value $sheetData.$($_.Name)
    }

> Get-Variable col*

Name                           Value
----                           -----
col1                           value1
col2                           value2
col3                           value3
```